# cakephp $this->redirect not working inside subdomain

Tags: routes, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to redirect from

```
sub.domain.com/login
```

to location

```
sub.domain.com/dashboard
```

Using `$this->redirect()` in cake php
But I getting redirected back to

```
sub.domain.com/login
```

Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever considered the possibility that you are not logged in?!

I will first need to authenticate with the server and then go to `/dashboard`. The sub-domain has nothing to do with this.